# Instantiating a type in its own class

Tags: java, object, instantiation

I cannot figure out what is wrong with this code

```
class Test {
    int a;
    Test() {
        a=10;
    }

    void new() {
        Test obj1=new Test();
        Test obj2=new Test();
        obj1.a=20;
        obj2.a=30;
    }

    void test(Test obj3,Test obj4) {
        new();
        obj3=obj1;
        obj4=obj2;
    }
}
```

Please someone explain what exactly is wrong with this code?

Comment: What is the compiler saying? You should read those messages.

Comment: Your usage of the `new` keyword is completely wrong, maybe you should begin with some simple Java tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Code to

```
class Test
{
int a;
Test obj1;
Test obj2;
Test()
{
a=10;
}
void tester()
{
    obj1=new Test();
    obj2=new Test();
    obj1.a=20;
    obj2.a=30;
}
void test(Test obj3,Test obj4)
{
tester();
obj3=obj1;
obj4=obj2;
}
}
```

And Try to learn about Scope in java and and `new` is reserved keyword

Comment: Doesn't solve what I think is the perceived intent of the `test` method though.

Comment: @Heuster sorry, I don't understand you?

Comment: @fge They won't effect but its a valid syntax :).

Answer (score 2):

Many things are wrong.

For one, `new` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use it for a method name;

Then, in this function:

```
void test(Test obj3,Test obj4)
{
    new();
    obj3=obj1;
    obj4=obj2;
}
```

`obj1` and `obj2` are not defined. One you get out of your "`new()` method", your `obj1` and `obj2` references fall out of scope and cannot be reached anymore;

Finally, `obj3` and `obj4` would not be affected by this `test()` method, since Java passes parameters by values, not references:

```
// doesn't work; when the caller returns, victim is still the same
public void changeInt(int victim)
{
    victim = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`obj1` and `obj2` are invisible inside the `test()` method. `void new()` is illegal method declaration as `new` is a keyword.

1. You need to declare `obj1` and `obj2` as instance method or need to pass it somehow to the `test()` method as parameter.
2. Rename the method `void new()` to something else.

My suggestions are only to resolve the compilation error . It doesn't account for the logical errors , if any , in the code.

Comment: oh yes,forgot about the scope